# Static variable in objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am somewhat confused about memory allocation of static variable in objective C.

1. should we allocate memory for static variable using `alloc:`? and
   initialize it using`init:`?
2. Is objective c static variable same as c static variable?
3. is it worth to apply `retain` on static variable?

Comment: Don't confuse the variable and the object pointed to by the value in the variable.  The variable doesn't care whether the value is an `alloced` object pointer or random bits.  What matters is what you're intending to do with the value stored in the variable, and the object it may point to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to take into account.

First, **static** C-like variables inside functions are technically fine. This should be:

```
- (void) f
{
    static NSString* s = nil;
    if (s == nil) {
        s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
    }
}
```

The problem is that you will probably never be able to `release`, since `s` scope is only `f` function.

This is exactly like a C static variable inside a function.

There is also `static` usage to control visibility of a variable in a translation unit. So, if you want to only allow some variable to be accessed within **file.c**, just like **C**, you need to write in that file:

```
static NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

Again, unless you write a specific method to release when you application ends, it will probably leak memory.

Finally, you can have "object oriented like" static behavior. You don't use `static` keyword here but as most object oriented languages, you can have **class variables** (in Java, C#, C++ and others, **class variables** are accomplished with the `static` keyword).

Comment: I don't see how not releasing the string poses a problem: There's no such thing as an `objc_deallocateClassPair` that would allow to deregister the class from the type system — which would be the only time when this object could safely be disposed of. BTW, the string example is misfortunate, as `-[NSString initWithString:]` returns its actual argument, if it is a literal — I think this holds for every immutable string, but am not entirely sure.

Comment: Very good explanation. +1. A simple question for you. When using static `keyword`, is there the chance to release the referenced object or does the object behaves like a singleton object which lives throughout the app lifecycle? Thank you.

Comment: @LorenzoBoaro once you declared static variable it will not release memory until you forcefully remove its reference. other =wise it will remains

Answer (score 4):

I only have answers to the first two of your questions — because I don't understand what you mean by your third one.

Let me start with question 2.:

> Is objective c static variable same as c static variable?

Objective C (ObjC) is, basically, just plain-old-C (POC) — and a nifty dynamic runtime, that adds a lot of fancy.

This means that every C language qualifier (e.g. `static`) works in ObjC *exactly* like it would in POC.
So the answer to that question is: **yes**.

With that cleared, back to number one:

> should we allocate memory for static variable using alloc:? and initialize it usinginit:?

The important thing about ObjC you need to always be aware of is, that there are no stack objects:

- Every object you'll ever use lives on the heap.
- From that follows that it is irrelevant in which *scope* (be it stack-local, `static` or global) you declare your object-type variables, in general, they will always be effectively `alloc`/`init`ed.

There is one exception to these rules:
Blocks at least start out as stack variables — but those are funny creatures, anyway.

So, to answer this question: **You actually don't have a choice!**

---

**Aside**

if you're using `static`s for objects other than literal `NSStrings` — which might well be totally reasonable — consider wrapping them with a proper class-method, for sanity's sake.

This is a nice way of doing it:

```
+ (NSNumber *)theMagicNumber
{
   static NSNumber *magicNumber;
   static dispatch_once_t numberSemaphore;
   dispatch_once( &numberSemaphore, ^{
      magicNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];  //  1
      [magicNumber retain];                      //  2
   } );

   return magicNumber;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. As you probably know `+[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` returns an autoreleased object!
2. Since we want to hold on to this object, we need to `retain` it, as usual — or compile our code using ARC and get rid of lines like this, altogether!

I hope this example answers or at least helps you figuring out the answer to your last question.